# Ubuntu 16.04 command line interface

Tags: 16.04

I recently went from Ubuntu-14.04 to Ubuntu-16.04 using the on-line upgrade 'button'.
I want the command line interface to be  'tcsh'.  How do I do this?
When I type  'which set setenv', I get NO response.  Why are these commands
missing?

Comment: You should use `chsh`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, are you sure you have tcsh installed in your system. By default shell is **bash**. If you are so specific to have tcsh as your default shell first check you have installed it your system and know its path by using the following command

```
which tcsh
```

if its installed you can see the path where its installed, I assume by default it could be */bin/tcsh*. Now check it is in the file /etc/shells. If yes now you can change the your default shell from bash to tcsh by issuing the following command

```
usermod -s /bin/tcsh USERNAME
```

use your system username instead in the above command. Thats it.

Comment: Instead of `usermod ...` one could also use `chsh -s /bin/tcsh`. But yours is correct too.

Comment: @ByteCommander  Now a days I like to be more formal. Thanks for notifying it.